# rails 5: rails c doesn't show line number on error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, irb, rails-console

I'm running rails 5, upgraded from 4.2.x

In the console and when running methods that fail, the error 
doesn't show the line number, I only get to see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

I made sure development.rb has:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails',              '5.1.2'     # mothership
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'                  # crutches
  gem 'sass-rails'                      # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'devise'                          # login/sessions
  gem 'devise-i18n'                     # login/sessions
  gem 'haml'                            # markup language
  gem 'uglifier',           '>= 1.3.0'  # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'jquery-rails'                   # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
  gem 'bcrypt',             '~> 3.1.7'  # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
  gem 'html5_validators'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'listen'

  group :development do
    gem 'rails_db'
    gem 'hirb'
    gem "better_errors"
    gem "binding_of_caller"
  end

  group :production do
    gem 'aws-sdk-rails'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
  end
```

What should I change so I get to see line where error occurs?

Comment: I called a method on a model class from the console.

Comment: from memory, the console often doesn't give line numbers... call it from a spec and you should get them...

Comment: they're in your log file, check `log/development.rb`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do something like this in the console:

```
begin
  your_method_call
rescue => e
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

You will be able to rescue the exception and print the backtrace. You don't have to `puts` it, you can do whatever you want with the backtrace, but you get the idea.

Hope this help.

Comment: I write this in console: `begin; Assessment.last.score; rescue => e; puts e.backtrace; end`
I get `=> nil`

Comment: `puts` will return nil, but the backtrace should be printed through standard output. Besides that, instead of `puts`, you can assign `e` to a variable and try to access `e.backtrace` manually.